# How to show campaign based on data tracked/reported by adobe sitecatalyst?

Tags: aem, adobe-analytics, campaign-monitor

We are implementing SiteCatalyst on flat HTML files. There is a requirement where we need to show campaigns based on the data that we reported from Analytics. e.g. There is a form having multiple fields. If user have not filled the form/or filled the form, we will track this event and report it to omniture. Now if he presses back button without filling the form completely, we need to show him some campaign/offers. The same will happen when he presses the submit button only the campaign will be different this time. Can this be achieved ? Can we integrate sitecatalyst and campaigning ?

I know that the vice-versa is possible. We can track campaigns and report the campaign id's. But is there any way to display offers based on the analytics data. That too in real time.

Any help would be great !
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you are looking for is Adobe Target.

Adobe Target is a tool that allows you to do AB/MV testing, but also target visitors by set rules and criteria.

Very simple example:

"If user came from foo.com, show `<h1>foo</h1>`. If user came from bar.com, show `<h1>bar</h1>`"

There is a level of integration between Adobe Target and Adobe Analytics. However, it is not real-time for data that has already been collected.

For example, if you have logic that pops `s.prop10` on page with "foo" then that can be integrated with Adobe Target and you can setup a rule that says something like "If s.prop10 is 'foo' then show '`<h1>foo</h1>`'".

But, it does not let you make a rule like "if prop10 was 'foo' for this visitor at any point in the time in the past, show '`<h1>foo</h1>`'".  In other words, there is no real-time evaluation of data already collected on Adobe's servers.

But, if you were simply wanting to make rules based off the current visit, you can store information in cookies look at cookies to make rules in Adobe Target easy enough.

Also note that there are no built-in tools or hooks or methods etc.. for the actions you described. For example, there's no way to natively say in Adobe Target (or Adobe Analytics) "If a visitor clicks the back button or does this other action, track that". You need to write your own code to define those actions and trigger relevant tracking code at relevant times.  Adobe Analytics (and other tracking tools) can help automate some basic stuff like simple link clicks or form field focusing - IOW *direct* 1:1 actions, but baking in complex actions like that is not feasible for a tracking tool, because every site and scenario is unique.

I guess the TL;DR here is that there is no magic wand for this sort of thing, not for Adobe or any other analytics/tracking tool; you're going to have to write your own code (be it server-side, client-side, or mix of both) to meet your business needs.

Comment: Thanks Crayon. We are now using Neolane connector to connect with Analytics server. So it is going to be like this:

Adobe Campaign>>Neolane>>Omniture

We tried this way and we can see the segments that we create in Omniture server are actually reflecting in Adobe campaigning tool. Now based on those segments we are trying to write some conditions to display offers.

Though it doesn't sound like real time but the scheduler runs every hour which extracts the segments and saves it to the campaign data base.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Reporting API exposed by adobe sitecatalyst.
Through the Reporting API, you’re able to access the reports generated for your Form events. If you’re using SiteCatalyst 15, you’ll be able to generate reports based on segments also. Recently the Reporting API was updated and given the ability to perform multi-level breakdowns across reports. For more information on this method, go to the [API documentation](https://marketing.adobe.com/developer/documentation/analytics-reporting-1-4/) within the Adobe Developer Connection.
Sample Real time access API:

```
// Real-Time Report
// Note the inclusion of "source" equals "realtime"
// Make sure you configure Real-Time reports for the report suite
https://api.omniture.com/admin/1.4/rest/?method=Report.Run
{
    "reportDescription": {
        "source": "realtime",
        "reportSuiteID": "rsid",
        "metrics": [
            { "id": "revenue" }
        ]
    }
}
```